# Driving transmission line

Tags: mosfet

I want to drive a high capacitance transmission line with a 3.3V, 200MHz square wave. The transmission line has a capacitance of 48pF/m, impedance is 150Ohm.

Someone recommended me to drive the line with a MOSFET push-pull stage. How do I know hoch much current will be sourced into the transmission line?

Comment: You can use Ohm's law to calculate it. You have the voltage and the impedance already.

Comment: Check one of my post - You will find a simple method for wave propagating ... https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572096/transient-analysis-of-inductor-circuit-and-back-emf/572131#572131

Comment: I would use a gate driver IC, or just parallel some fast logic IC's.

Comment: While the signal is in flight and the reflection has not come back to the source, the line looks like a resistor with the transmission line impedance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *The transmission line has a capacitance of 48pF/m, impedance is
> 150Ohm.*

If the transmission line is terminated in the correct  impedance (150 Ω) and, is driven directly by the 3.3 volt peak amplitude square wave then, the peak current is identical to driving a 150 Ω load directly i.e. 22 mA peak.

At this frequency, when driving a transmission line, the capacitance per metre is of no-consequence because the transmission line behaves like  errr... um... a transmission line.

This is because the transmission line has inductance per metre and, when you go about calculating the impedance of the transmission line you'll find this: -

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{L}{C}}$$

Hence, with your values, L = 1.08 μH

You can also drive the t-line with a series impedance of 150 Ω if the t-line output runs into an open circuit (impedance higher than a few kΩ is practical).

Scenario A and scenario B side by side: -

[image]

The graph is for the current from the source. Red is current from source into a t-line terminated in 150 Ω Blue is a source-series termination of 150 Ω and an open circuit t-line.

Comment: and if the transmission line is open end, or short circuit without a termination?

Comment: You get reflections.... is that what you want?

Comment: yes but will the current stay the same?

Comment: If it’s a transmission line then (at least) each half-wave of the signal has been sent on its way before it gets to the other end, so the transmitter doesn’t get to see the load on the other end, unless there are reflections that could have any phase difference from the transmitter, depending on the length and the termination.

Comment: @Yoomo the peak input current with a load termination at the end will be +22 mA. The peak current with a series driving termination will be +/- 11mA.

Comment: @Frog incorrect - the t-line acts as a load the instant anything changes at the input  - that "load" may change with time due to reflections but, at the instant the voltage is applied, the t-line will look like a 150 ohm load to the source voltage.

Comment: @Yoomo I recommend the falstad simulator for seeing how the signals interact,as you see it traveling over the line: https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCCsCmC0YCZwAYB0DnIQdmwZmQA4EA2ATjOymRAVUmqjjDACgxsIOTaAWG3mR4J+IGnlRg4hcJBqEayVgHdw2YaMQyRileAQy8GNTyO7VgjTUiI+5kJZBmot50oBOUXr1rYkkbydjGjA5VgA3EBIfZ2i7MVpaTGTk2no0hkV6PS0gmji3Vk84nX1tURCwz0gyJBx-WryE0I8o0Xq28WDZJVUAmOMapEK+xtjREc6mkkJDYL0ZufzZ3yRerx9Sofj17dLomlL1g-jFndYAZw3V66OEgDMAQwAbC+hLqEaOvYrwECfXu8ricOiDfhAAW8PmdQSs7hCXlC+rYtoEjnobMNBoFCgBzBxCJqOPB4Hi6fHcJqUklksSsAD2URAMgEpLwUDEqCwmUSpgZTmZCV4bI5aG5f2GTlYQA

Comment: @Ferrybig please don't make recommendations of inferior products. Micro-cap is free and is probably as good as it gets in terms of simulators. Falstad might suit a hobbyist or someone more interested in coding but it's not really suitable for pro simulations.

Comment: @andyaka "at the instant the voltage is applied, the t-line will look like a 150 ohm load to the source voltage". That is a good approximation, but only an approximation. If a step voltage input is applied to an infinite transmission line (with non-zero loss) the current is not a step, but ramps up (as if the voltage source sees an inductance, and not a pure resistance. There is a TI app note that discusses/shows this. The ramp time is short, and the usual issue with t-lines is reflections, so it isn't often discussed.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy please link that TI paper.

Comment: @Andyaka the app note from my memory was [snla026a](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snla026a/snla026a.pdf). However, upon re-reading, it is not what I had hoped. Figure 10 has current associated with a step voltage input for lengths such as  3750 ft., but the graphic is so poor/unclear that it is almost useless. We can discuss in chat if you like, or I or you could write a Q so that I could provide more details. Very short explanation is that with losses, a xmit line impedance is frequency dependent, and @ high enough frequencies impedance is inductive. i rise time with step v is related to Bessel.

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy you could write a canonical question and supply your own answer. Normally I'd be tempted but really busy (as I'm sure you are).

Comment: I've just read that app note and I think it's very confusing (or the writer was confused). In short I disagree about the stuff you mention earlier above.

Answer (score 0):

How you terminate or drive the line depends on the length of the line the number of loads or the way the loads are distributed.

1. Single load at distant end. this is the easiest and simplest. You simply put a series matching resistor at the driving end, but must be able to source and leave the distant end open cct or a few thousand Ohm load Input impedance of gate or transistor. If this can be achieved you will have to be able to source and sink 11 mA into a total series terminating impedance of 150 Ohm's. this will consist of some Ohm's in the driver, say 20 and the remainder in a resistor of 130. this sytem relies on the recieve end having a sufficiently high impedance to allow the 1.65 voltage traveling down the line to instantly double at the receive end. Is that not pretty cool?
   The best way to drive the line is probably using a special line driving integrated cct. They are specially designed to source and sink the same amount of current, and be roughly symmetrical in impedance to enable a simple series matching resistor to match for both 0 and 1. ..…………..I’ll answer this question in about 3 parts. The where and how of line driving IC’s and techniques for driving many loads in a daisy chain fashion etc.